# Wildfly version in JBoss EAP 7.1.0

Tags: wildfly, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I am using Java 8 to build my application and planning to use JBoss EAP 7.1.0 for production deployment, but I am not getting which version of Wildfly ships with JBoss EAP 7.1.0. I find Wildfly core 3.0.1 but what is Wildfly core?

Also is it recomended to update the Java version of JBoss EAP 6.4 to Java 8 and use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WildFly is not shipped with the EAP. WildFly is a community project and JBoss EAP is a Red Hat product. They live in separate repositories and even if they usually have some common point in history, you can't say WildFly is shipped with EAP. The closest WildFly version to EAP 7.1 is WildFly 11.

To simplify creating layered projects/products, the core runtime of the application server was cut to a separate project - the [WildFly core](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core). It contains just a very basic functionality which allow to build projects on top of it (by adding modules and extensions). The core contains

- Modular class loading
- Unified management, including domain mode
- Basic deployment architecture
- CLI for management

Java 8 is supported for JBoss EAP 6.4. For details look into the [EAP 6 supported configurations](https://access.redhat.com/articles/111663).

Comment: I know that JBoss AS 7.5.0 ships with JBoss EAP 6.4. Waht is the AS version that ships with JBoss EAP 7.1.0? Also if I do not use EAP but Wildfly in my production, will I get the support from JBoss or is it recommended? We have jdk 1.7 in JBoss EAP 6.4 in production, since it supports Oracle jdk 1.8, we can install jdk 1.8 in JBoss EAP 6.4, right?

Comment: Red Hat dooesn't support WildFly, only JBoss EAP. And yes you can run your EAP 6.4  application on Java 8 with support.

Comment: >>> Waht is the AS version that ships with JBoss EAP 7.1.0?
EAP Version 7.1.0 is based on Wildfly 11

Comment: >>>  We have jdk 1.7 in JBoss EAP 6.4 in production, since it supports Oracle jdk 1.8, we can install jdk 1.8 in JBoss EAP 6.4, right?

- JBoss EAP supports Oracle JDK 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8(** support only with EAP 6.3.3 update and above**)

Answer (score 6):

There is an article that explains the mapping:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-eap/what-is-the-difference-between-jboss-eap-wildfly-and-jboss-as

JBoss EAP Version   WildFly Version
JBoss EAP 7.2   WildFly 14.0.1
JBoss EAP 7.1   WildFly 11
JBoss EAP 7.0   WildFly 10
JBoss EAP 6.4   JBoss AS 7.5
JBoss EAP 6.3   JBoss AS 7.4
JBoss EAP 6.2   JBoss AS 7.3
JBoss EAP 6.1   JBoss AS 7.2
JBoss EAP 6.0   JBoss AS 7.1

JBoss is *based on* (not bundled with) Wildfly.