# Confused by wildfly versions used in EAP 7.2

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I would have added this to another thread, but I am unable to comment on other's posts.  And what I read did not answer my question.  I just installed EAP 7.2.0.GA.  In the console log, it says:

```
JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001)
```

However, others think it is around version 13.  And when I look at the releases of wildfly ( http://wildfly.org/downloads/ ) a version 6 is so old it does not even show up and would have been prior to 2014...

So, how can it be 6.0.11.Final?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WildFly core is just a component in WildFly application server.
As such is also used in JBoss EAP which is a downstream product based on WildFly AS.

WildFly core is standalone project which provides most of core capabilities (management, cli, administration, subsystem infrastructure...) of the application server without any Java EE support, that is added to it by WildFly project.

you can see the sources for both at 
https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/
https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/

as for your confusion.

WildFly core 6.0.x is used in EAP 7.1 as well as in WildFly 14
which you an see also in the sources https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/14.0.0.Final/pom.xml#L375

micro version is not always exactly the same, as in the process of building downstream product of EAP, extra patches can be added.

Comment: Well, that is not confusing at all :-)  Thanks for explaining the huge difference in version numbers and two products.

Answer (score 1):

`WildFly Core` is a component in `JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7` (`EAP 7`). So, this log means:

- `JBoss EAP 7.2` - `JBoss` `EAP` in version `7.2`
- `GA` - General availability
- `WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final` - component `WildFly Core` in version `6.0.11.Final`.

See also:

- [JBoss Enterprise Application Platform Component Details](https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_7)
- [Software release life cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle)

Comment: That is the way I read it as well.  But what confuses me is the information from the http://wildfly.org/downloads/ site.  Are these different than the WildFly Core?  The earliest version on wildfly.org shows wildfly 8.0.0.Final was available 2014-02-11.  And 6.0.11.Final would be even earlier.  Perhaps the WildFly versions in EAP are not the same as the ones from wildfly.org?

Comment: @JayWitherspoon, exactly. From the download link: `The technology behind WildFly is also available in JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 7.`. So, core is used by `WildFly` project and `JBoss EAP`. See [Wildfly version in JBoss EAP 7.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432021/wildfly-version-in-jboss-eap-7-1-0)